# Single YAML file with multiple load balancers and pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a single yaml file in which I am attempting to deploy 2 load balancers, each with a single pod and container.

[image: 2 Load balancers each with a pod and 1 container]

However, when I run the following infrastructure.yml file it starts 2 load balancers and only 1 pod / container (`job-base`). It is ignoring starting the `api-base` pod / container. Commenting out the `job-base` job / container from the file and the `api-base` pod starts properly.

What am I missing? How do I get this single file to deploy all pods, and services?

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: api-base
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-base
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-base
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-base
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api-base
        image: path/to/apiImage
        ports:
        - containerPort: 44360
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "0.4Gi"
            cpu: "0.2"
          limits:
            memory: "0.4Gi"
            cpu: "0.2"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: api-base
   labels:
      app: api-base
   annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
spec:
   selector:
      app: api-base
   ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 44360
      protocol: TCP
   type: LoadBalancer
---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: job-base
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: job-base
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: job-base
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: job-base
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: job-base
        image: path/to/jobImage
        ports:
        - containerPort: 44360
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "0.4Gi"
            cpu: "0.2"
          limits:
            memory: "0.4Gi"
            cpu: "0.2"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: job-base
   labels:
      app: job-base
   annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
spec:
   selector:
      app: job-base
   ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 44360
      protocol: TCP
   type: LoadBalancer
```

**Update:**

If it is not possible to accomplish this in a single yml I would also consider running the `api` and `job` containers in the same pod using the same load balancer. As long as I can expose each container within the pod on a different port.

Comment: Did you try to separate deployments ? e.g `api-base.yaml`, `job-base.yaml`

Comment: I am confined to this single infrastructure.yml due to my requirements. I have also tried to have a single pod with multiple containers. However, I am unsure how to expose each container using the load balancer inside a single pod. I would also accept a answer of how to do this.

Comment: I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work.
You need to troubleshoot/provide more details on the situation when you apply that yaml file.
Are both deployments created? Are replica sets created? Are there any events in deployments/replicasets?

Comment: Could you add more info/logs? What is printed when you `kubectl apply` your single file? Is the deployment created (`kubectl get deployment`)? If yes, then execute `kubectl describe` to analyze what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace did not have enough resources allocated. When the new container would attempt to be provisioned it would fail and terminate due to CPU or Memory limits.

I discovered the issue by running the following command

```
kubectl get deployment api-base -o yaml
```

This output a `message` property which indicated that the latest deployment failed due to resource issues.

Increasing the namespaces ResourceQuota resolved the issue: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/quota-memory-cpu-namespace/